# Не добавляется сss свойство через jquery

Tags: javascript, css, веб-программирование, запрос

Не могу понять почему не меняется свойство у ссылки, при нажатии, при этом класс добавляется

Вот сам код

```
$(function() {
    $(".item-list-dir").click(function () {
        $(".item-list-dir").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");

        $(this).hasClass("kitchen").css("background-color", "yellow");
    });
});
```

Comment: сделайте код сниппетом в вопрос, в аду есть специальное место для тех кто код публикует скриншотом.

Comment: Не увидел, спасибо)

Comment: интересно, что возвращает `hasClass`? и есть ли у этого чего-тa метод `css`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/

```
if ($(this).hasClass("kitchen"))
  $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает)

Comment: @DenisPenkov Еще бы! Слева галочка - щёлк :).

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте так:

```
if ($(this).hasClass("kitchen")){
    $(this).css({backgroundColor: "yellow"});
}
```

Документация для функции [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-function).

Answer (score 0):

Заменил hasClass на filter.

```js
$(function() {
    $(".item-list-dir").click(function () {
        $(".item-list-dir").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");

        //$(this).hasClass("kitchen").css("background-color", "yellow");
        $(this).filter(".kitchen").css("background-color", "yellow");
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

<a class='item-list-dir kitchen'>Нажми меня</a>
```